# deserialize JSON with Ktor client

Tags: json, kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I'm new to Kotlin and trying Ktor `3.0.0-beta-1` to build API.  I managed to build a route and it's working when I access `localhost:port/api/path/to/route`, but I'm having trouble testing it.

According to https://ktor.io/docs/3.0.0-beta-1/serialization-client.html
I should be able to create client and test the route like this:

```
class ApplicationTest {
    val client = HttpClient() {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
    }
    @Test
    fun testRoute() = testApplication {
        application {}
        val value: ReturnedValue = client.get("/api/path/to/route").body()
    }
}
```

but have error `Unresolved reference: body`

I also tried

```
    client.get("/api/path/to/route").apply {
        assertEquals(ReturnedValue(), body<ReturnedValue>())
    }
```

because there was an autogenerated test case

```
    client.get("/").apply {
        assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, status)
        assertEquals("Hello World!", bodyAsText())
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you have `import io.ktor.client.call.*` or `import io.ktor.client.call.body` at the top of your file

Comment: Thank you @SimonJacobs, that was indeed missing.  However, after adding the import I have `io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException`

Comment: You have to create a client using the `createClient` extension function.

Comment: Thank you @AlekseiTirman, I figured out that it is in `io.ktor.server.testing.ClientProvider.createClient` but got `Cannot importcreateClient, functions and properties can be imported only from packages or objects`

Comment: To make it work, you need to have the following import: `import io.ktor.server.testing.testApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working, thank you commenters!

```
import io.ktor.client.call.body
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.client.request.get
import io.ktor.client.statement.bodyAsText
import io.ktor.http.HttpStatusCode
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.json
import io.ktor.server.testing.testApplication
import kotlin.test.assertEquals
import kotlin.test.Test

class ApplicationTest {
    @Test
    fun testItem() = testApplication {
        val client = createClient {
            install(ContentNegotiation) {
                json()
            }
        }
        client.get("/api/path/to/route").apply {
            val item: ReturnedValue = body()
        }
    }
}
```

Since I'm new to Kotlin, it was hard to find what is and should be coming from where.

- The import for `body`, which @simon-jacobs pointed out, was missing from the article.  I posted the question after ChatGPT and Google didn't help me finding where to import it from.
- Initially generated trivial testing code was like `testApplication {client...}`, which was using default client.  Following the article, I switched to trying to create one by `HttpClient`, which does not apply to testing.  Thanks to @aleksei-tirman, I finally understood that I have to use `createClient` and that it is a dedicated way to create a client, with the context provided by `testApplication` (so only callable inside).

  - This is explained in https://ktor.io/docs/3.0.0-beta-1/testing.html#configure-client
  - Both default `client` and customizable `createClient` are coming from `ClientProvider` → `ApplicationTestBuilder` → `testApplication`.  It is easy to find out, only after knowing the answer.
- [`apply` is a scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#apply) which confused me by making methods, extension functions and normal functions indistinguishable.  It makes the code shorter but does no actual work.  When I read the code I have to take care of it, but no need for use by myself.